# Как сделать слайдер для интервала дат

Tags: node.js, slider, reactjs

Требуется изобразить слайдер с заданием интервала с минимальной датой год назад и максимальной сегодня, чтобы можно было менять обе границы независимо. Какой компонент надо использовать и как его вставить в проект, написанный на nodejs с использованием ReactJs? И желательно, чтобы дата, через которую в данный момент протаскиваешь, показывалась сверху или снизу.

Comment: Может не стоит использовать слайдер в данном случае? Пользователи могут Вас возненавидеть, если пользоваться будут с тач-устройств, либо с не очень хороших мышек (в случае низкого разрешения так же возможны проблемы)

Comment: А при чём тут node.js?

Comment: И почему именно слайдер? Похоже, что Вы ищите **datepicker**

Comment: Я ищу именно слайдер, то есть такую полоску, по которой двигаются 2 ограничителя интервала. И проект сделан на nodeJs.

Answer (score 1):

Вот неплохой плагин, который не тянет за собой ничего, не реклама, недавно выручил меня в проекте, где не желательно было тащить лишний JS: http://refreshless.com/nouislider/